# How to apply the mean-value theorem to prove

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

$f$ is a function that is continuous on $[a, b]$ and differentiable on $(a, b)$. Suppose that there exists $c \in (a, b)$ such that $f(c) > f(a)$ and $f(c) > f(b)$. Prove that there exists $d \in (a, b)$ at which $f'(d) = 0$

This reminds me of Rolle's theorem, for which if $f(a) = f(b)$, then $\exists c \in (a, b)$ such that $f'(c) = 0$ But here, I think it's not necessarily clear that $c \in (a, b)$ such that $f(c) > f(a)$ and $f(c) > f(b)$ implies $f(a) = f(b)$. Given all the conditions, it makes sense that $f$ has a local maximum at $d$. However, I don't know how to apply the MVT to prove this. Any hints would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a start:

$${f(c)-f(a)\over c-a}>0$$

So, by the mean value theorem, there is a $d_1\in(a,c)$ such that ${f(c)-f(a)\over c-a}=f'(d_1)>0$.

Now, what can you say about ${f(b)-f(c)\over b-c}$?

Comment: ${f(b)-f(c)\over b-c} = f'(d_2) < 0$? For some $d_2 \in (c, b)$. Since slope is positive for $d \in (a, c)$ and slope is negative for $d_2 \in (c, b)$. Given all the conditions, intuitively I would think that there's a maximum at some point in $(a, b)$. However, I still don't see how I can rigorously prove this?

Comment: You're almost there. I've edited my notation slightly. So, at this point you have $d_1,d_2\in(a,b)$ with $d_1<d_2$, and $f'(d_1)>0$ and $f'(d_2)<0$.  Now, apply the intermediate value theorem.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: If $f(a)=f(b)$ this is just Rolle's theorem. If $f(a)<f(b)$ use the intermediate value theorem to find $\xi \in (a,c)$ such that $f(\xi)=f(b)$.